# How to embed a Google Map iFrame with a custom name

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

Currently, I am using the following iFrame

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=APIKEYHERE&q=-34.753608,149.720462" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Although, when rendered, the name of the location is the longitude and latitude, the the below image.

Is it possible to add in a name as a parameter for it to be displayed at the top left of the iFrame instead of the longitude and latitude? There's the option to use the locations name as the `q`, although some addresses cannot be found, and longitude and latitude is more accurate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a current limitation of the Embed API. However, this is easy enough with the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details). It is more work, but is much more flexible and powerful.